# What does rating a memory sequence do?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

At the end of a memory sequence you have the option to rate it. What is the purpose of this.

Is it used in-game by Abstergo in some way, or does it get sent to Ubisoft for them to use however they like?

Answer (score -1):

The ratings are sent back to Ubisoft, who can then do whatever they want with them.

> Ubisoft is actually using all of this data to improve future games.
>
> Ubisoft has been using data tracking to improve our titles for a while, but this is the first time we will be able to match gameplay metrics to player appreciation in order to dig even deeper into player behavior.
>
> The combination of the two data sources will give us incredible insight into how players are interacting with our game and guide future development teams to create missions that appeal to our players even more.
>
> [(Source)](http://www.nowgamer.com/news/2145681/assassins_creed_4_black_flag_best_mission_revealed_by_ubisoft.html)

They have absolutely no effect on gameplay.